# Release a lock on a dll loaded by a defunct process; Windows 10

Tags: windows, dll, process, termination

I'm working on a DLL for a process that runs on Windows 10.  The process has known termination issues that are not in my scope to address.  One of those issues is that when the process terminates, I cannot update my own DLL because, according to Windows, that process has that DLL still loaded, even though the process appears nowhere in, for example, Process Explorer.  So, my question is, is there a way to force Windows to release that DLL without having to restart Windows?

Comment: How did Windows communicate that a non-existent process has some module mapped? How did Windows refer to that process?

Answer (score 0):

DLL (Dynamic Link Library) This Library Doesn't Show Up until the Program is running. If You Want to Change the Contents of DLL the Program Should Terminate.
If It Doesn't terminate try Closing it in the Task Manager [NOTE: The Program can be Running as an Background Process].
For full reference Check this Documentation out
-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library